# Question for finding the value of an expression.

Tags: polynomials

I was just solving a mathematics worksheet that my teacher gave to me and I am having a problem with one question. The question is:

> If $ab+bc+ca = 0$, then find the value of $1/(a^2-bc) + 1/(b^2-ca) +
>  1/(c^2-ab)$

I am confused whether we have to use any identity in solving this or its just something else.

Please if someone can help it would be best for me.

Comment: Presumably one also assumes $a$, $b$, and $c$ are nonzero

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$a^2 - bc = a^2 + ab + ac = a(a + b + c)$$

Comment: How?? can you expand?

Comment: Please try with it first and show where you get stuck.

Comment: No I am asking how you got the above hint?

Comment: Well it looks evident to me...$bc$ appears 2 times, so it's worth trying do something with it.

Comment: I guess thats correct.. Thanks a lot